# Data annotations for input fields with out html helper methods

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want to bind the data annotations for the input fields but I am not interested to use html helpers to render my form. can any one suggest how to bind data annotations to plain html input fields with out using html helper methods.

```
@Html.TextboxFor(model => model.UserName)
```

it automatically binds validation rule to this text box as we written required at model class
similarly I want same thing if i write like

```
<input type="text" name="UserName"/>
```

in also must validate through data annotation.

Comment: You you mean for client side validation using jquery.validate.unobtrusive?

Comment: @StephenMuecke nope I written data annotations @ server side model, I want to use same annotations by writing plain input with out writing Html helper method.  Similarly I wan to know how to write place-holder in html helper method.

Comment: Server side validation has got nothing to do with the `data-xxx` attributes rendered by the html helpers. They are only rendered for use by client side validation using jquery.validate. So if your not using client side validation they are not required

Answer (score 0):

The html attributes that you decorate your model/view model with are referenced via your models `ModelMetaData` object. By writing the plain HTML you're not going to be able to access that data as you're writing straight HTML.

There's not much of a way to get around this, though if push came to shove then your option would be:

Write some means of turning the `ModelMetaData` into a JSON object and then add the necessary attributes to the associative html input field, using the name as a reference to the property such as `name="Model.UserName"`.

Out of interest, why are you determind not to use the HTML helpers? Would you be happy to write your own HTML helpers?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have a situation like I need to show placeholder text in different language, I can able to access value from resource file but not able to assign that to textbox if i write html helper, but i can able to assign same by using plain html element, if i write plain html my annotation got missed.